# Get value of same class but diff id of checkbox, when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of the checkbox when #catDelete is clicked.

Below is the html code

```
<?php $i=1; do { ?>
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_cat['cat']; ?>" class="checkboxcat" id="<?php echo $i; ?>"  name="catcheckbox" style="border:#cccccc 1px solid; background-color:#fff;"><?php echo $row_cat['cat']; ?>
<span id="CatDelete" style="position:relative; left:10px; color:#ff0000; font-size:10px;">Delete</span>
<?php $i++; } while ($row_cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($cat)); ?>
```

jquery code - It gives me the value of the first checkbox

```
$('#CatDelete').click(function(){
alert($('.checkboxcat').attr('id'));
});
```

Any help appreciated. Did search if there was a duplicate question, but did not find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown much of your stucture, but it looks like the checkbox is a sibling element prior to the span. If so:

```
$("#CatDelete").click(function() {
    var val = $(this).prevAll('input').first().val();
    console.log(val);
});
```

That starts from the clicked element, works backward through siblings looking for `input` elements, grabs the first one, and gets its value.

But you've edited the question now to say it's in a loop. You **cannot** have more than one element with the same `id` ("CatDelete"). You'll need to change the span to use a class instead, and then change the above to use that class. So for instance, if you change it to use the *class* "CatDelete", then:

```
// v--- Note the change
$(".CatDelete").click(function() {
    var val = $(this).prevAll('input').first().val();
    console.log(val);
});
```

[Live Working Copy](http://jsbin.com/iboqev/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iboqev/1/edit)

But I think I'd probably adjust the structure slightly so that you're not hunting through sibling elements like that. If you put each pair (checkbox and button) inside a container, like a `div`, you can do something a bit more straightforward to find the matching `input`:

```
var val = $(this).closest('div').find('input').val();
```

E.g.

```
$(".CatDelete").click(function() {
    var val = $(this).closest('div').find('input').val();
    console.log("The value for the checkbox is: " + val);
});
```

[Live Working Copy](http://jsbin.com/iboqev/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iboqev/2/edit)

Comment: I have the same class with different id $i++

Comment: @Jean: Again, your "CatDelete" span, which is what you've said you want to detect clicks on, doesn't have `$i++` or anything. You're outputting more than one element with the `id` "CatDelete", according to your code. That's invalid.

Comment: @TJ So if I have a $i++ for the #catdelete?

Comment: @Jean: I've already shown you how to do it. Don't muck about with `id` values with `$i++` or whatever. Use a class, and then look at the value of the preceding `input`.